# VS Code Python paste and indent

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I saw other VS Code questions here, so I decided to ask one myself, as their GitHub issues are no so frequently visited. So basically I have one issue with copying and pasting python code in VS Code. I've got `autopep8` as my formatter (but tried `yapf` also, so I guess its not a formatter issue). Let me illustrate this issue:

I've got this code:

```
def show_events():
    a = 0
    if a == 0:
```

I want to paste this block of code inside of `if`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Calendar.db')
c = conn.cursor()
data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM RepetitiveEvent')
for row in data:
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

So I go to the next line (like 4 on the first one code sample), it gets autoindented for me. Now I press `Ctrl+V` and I would like to see this:

```
def show_events():
    a = 0
    if a == 0:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Calendar.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM RepetitiveEvent')
        for row in data:
            print(row)
        conn.close()
```

But instead I see this:

```
 def show_events():
    a = 0
    if a == 0:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Calendar.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM RepetitiveEvent')
    for row in data:
        print(row)
    conn.close()
```

After pressing `Ctrl+S` to save and format (even though I have `editor.formatOnPaste` set to `true` it just unindents the first line:

```
def show_events():
    a = 0
    if a == 0:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Calendar.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM RepetitiveEvent')
    for row in data:
        print(row)
    conn.close()
```

After googling for a while I found that extension, that people would suggest to use `Python Paste and Indent`. I've installed it, I bound `Ctrl+Shift+V` to `pyPasteIndent.pasteAndIndent`. The result of copying would be as this:

```
def show_events():
    a = 0
    if a == 0:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('Calendar.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        data = c.execute('SELECT * FROM RepetitiveEvent')
        for row in data:
            print(row)
        conn.close()
```

So my question would be: Is there a way to actually make it work the way it is expected to do?

Comment: How should the auto indent know at what indentation level your code lines should be?

Comment: Don't be mad at me, on Visual Studio it does work. And, well, how? If you paste two lines at column 8 (so like under if statement in a function), then it should paste those lines on column 8, not one on 8 and the other one on 4

Comment: At first I'm not mad at you I just ask a question. And what you are writing is just one valid interpretation of what could be the desired result. "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess." -- The zen of Python

Comment: @Frynio I check every issue that has a comment almost every day at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/ so I'm not sure where you get the impression we don't check our issue tracker.

Comment: Comparing issue tracker to SO, well

Answer (score 2):

VS Code still doesn't properly support copypasting multiple lines of code in Python.

You can do it with extensions such as [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LesGrieve.paste-indent).
But this one only adds `paste-indent` command.

That's why you'll have to setup keyboard shortcuts. To do that:

1. File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
2. This will open GUI. There you can either configure it manually or you can press Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON) and add these lines:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+v",
        "command": "extension.paste-indent",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python' && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

(Or change keybinding on whichever you like by editing `"ctrl+v"`. For example, you should change it to `"cmd+v"` if you're on MacOS)

Comment: This solution is a must for all VSCoders that use Python

Comment: HOnestly shocked at how bad copying and pasting python code is in vscode given how much effort has clearly gone into building out the rest of the python experience